# How to run a .jar file? No main class found

Tags: java

How do I run a `jar` file?

I tried this :
`java iCChecker.jar`

but I got next trace :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: iCChecker/jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: iCChecker.jar
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: iCChecker.jar.  Program will exit.
```

So, what am I doing wrong? And how to start this jar file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To run a jar file, pass the `-jar` option to java. Otherwise it assumes the given argument is the name of a class, not the name of a jar file (specifically in this case it's looking for a class named `jar` in a the package `iCChecker`).

So `java -jar iCChecker.jar` will work.